# Python sending email from different from address with gmail

Tags: php, python, email, smtp

I am trying to make an email look like it came from a specific user within our company for an automated client followup email. For some reason I cannot change the "FROM" to look like anyone but the account I log into gmail with.

I know for a fact that PHP mailer library can make the FROM address from anyone without any problems - but for some reason I can't in python. We have an enterprise gmail account if that helps.

Here is the code I am working with

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

def sendFollowupEmail(html):
  msg = MimeText('body')
  msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
  msg['From'] = "THIS IS THE EMAIL I WANT TO CHANGE@domain.com"
  msg['To'] = "client@client.com"




  username = 'accessaccount@gmail.com'
  password = 'password'
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
  server.starttls()
  server.login(username,password)  
  server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
  server.quit()    








  if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendFollowupEmail("test123")
```

Here is the PHP that will allow you to change from address to whatever you want

```
function sendFollowUpEmail($options) {

        /*
         * Send an email to a person or group.
         * Dependencies: PHPMailer
         * options: {
         *      'to' -> who to send the email to,
         *      'from'-> who the email was sent from,
         *      'subject'-> subject of the email,
         *      'body' -> the body of the email
         * }
         */
        $host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $username = "accessaccount@gmail.com";
        $password = "password";
        $port = 465;
        echo error_reporting(E_STRICT);

        require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $body = $options['body'];

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
        $mail->Host = $host; 
        $mail->Port = $port;
        $mail->Username = $username; 
        $mail->Password = $password;
        $mail->SetFrom($options['from'], $options['from']);

        if($options['bcc']!='') {
            $mail->AddBCC($options['bcc'], $options['bcc']);
        }

        //$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
        $mail->Subject = $options['subject'];
        $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $address = $options['to'];
        $mail->AddAddress($address);
        $mail->send();
```

Comment: Have you tried `server.sendmail(msg['From'], you, msg.as_string())`?

Comment: From my experience with git-format-patch I believe it's impossible to do this over smtp with gmail. I was trying to set my plussed address and it would not allow me to. I'm not certain though

Comment: You are able to do it with PHP - I know this for a fact. Not sure what the difference is

Comment: gmail may not allow you do this.

Comment: I didn't think it would but PHP allows you to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Add  to the msg

```
msg['Reply-To'] = "THIS IS THE EMAIL I WANT TO CHANGE@domain.com"
```

**Edit**

One thing you can do is add the return email in your ***Accounts and Import*** in gmail. and select it not as an alias. this will allow you to send emails from your main account as the other account. using the from address of the other account

Comment: That allows a reply to be sent to the email address but it still leaves the from as the account I use as access

Comment: Why a down vote? This follows the RFC 822 protocol that python follows.

Comment: @corn3lius how would one hide/change the `msg['From"]` email address so that it appears different?